# Procedure for creating a database locally using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've connected to mLab using `MongoClient.connect`, but now I want to create a local database rather than use mLab. I've tried changing the URL to "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb" to create a database locally as suggested, but I'm getting a `failed to connect to server` error. Is there anything I should install? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Yes. You are missing [actually installing a server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/). The nodejs driver does not install the mongodb server. It's just a driver for connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First**, install your mongoDB server: 
>   [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/](http://MongoDB%20Server%20Installation)

After that, you should be able to start your local **mongodb** server:

```
sudo service mongod start //in case of linux
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_environment.htm) the docs to start the mongodb server

> Then, you will type `mongo` and the client command line will start.
>   And when typing `use yourDatabase`, mongo will create the database if
>   it does not exist.

Then, your server will be up, and the database created. Anyway, check the docs if you need the guides for windows or other systems.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how server works and mlab works. mLab is a company who provide database as a services. Means you no need to handle server hurdles, they take care server , backups , infrastructure etc. They provide mongodb server , You just need to create database on mongodb server's and use them.

Now comes to main points.

If you want use mongodb on your local system then you first need to install mongodb on your local system and then connect it.